# Data fetching in preloaded SSR templates in next.js 13

Tags: next.js13

Consider I have a frontend application which will only display a form that users can fill.
`https://exampleApp/form/{id}`
Frontend is in next.js 13,
Now I want Server side rendering completley and consider for form data with id there is a seperate backend to which this next app will request first before returning the form HTML page.

Now how can I achieve this in next.js app, Like with the new app structure cannot use getServerSideProps any more.
Once the request is made next.js app should call backend API get formData and should give prerenderred HTML with form.
Thanks

Have tried many things but still not much progress